# Is there a way to add data to a Spark streaming job?

Tags: apache-spark

I have an existing app that represents customer data as an collection of graphs in a Spark 1.6 streaming job, multiple
graphs per customer. The job runs indefinitely, updating values within each graph over time. That is, our RDD is a
key-value RDD like `RDD[(graphId, graph)]`. A stream is created for applying queued messages to the graphs in the RDD
during each batch.

If I want to add a customer to a running job, is there a Spark way to do this? The RDD is immutable, so that rules out
adding a customer's graphs to the existing RDD. Adding a new stream with its associated input queue is not supported, so
that rules out adding a new stream to the context for the new customer. (`Adding new inputs, transformations, and output operations after starting a context is not supported`)
Adding a new context for each customer would be supported if `spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts` were supported in a
production environment.

In the worst case, I could save the existing customers' graphs, stop the stream, create a new RDD including the new
customer's data, and fire up a new stream. However, this has two issues - it disrupts processing on the existing
customers, and limits scalability as the number of customers grows.

Is there a way to create a new RDD that includes the existing graphs and new cutomer's graphs, then use that RDD to
replace the old one in the running stream? Are there options in newer versions of Spark, particularly 2.1?

Comment: Why union a new Dstream is not supported? originDstream.union(ssc.textFileStream()) can work

Comment: @ZhangTong - union is supported. The error comes trying to take that new stream, which includes input from a new queue, which is the problem. The resulting error when trying to add the new queue is `Adding new inputs, transformations, and output operations after starting a context is not supported`.

Comment: @don-branson any solution you found for this, I am also trying to do the same, where need to add dynamic input (kafka topic) via zookeeper listener.

Comment: @ASe - I did. I tried a variety of approaches which did not work. Here's what worked. Each key points to a value. For us, Each key points to a WorkItem. The change was to set up the RDD so that each key points to a list of WorkItems. Then we can add and remove items from the list.